# Replace a string with current date and time with sed -E before creating the output file

Tags: sed, terminal

I'm trying to generate a file to keep the log of average CPU usage.

```
sudo mpstat 1 5 | grep Average | sed -E 's|Average:|$(date)|g' > cpu_usage_test.txt
```

I'm trying to replace the text "Average:" with the current date and time. Tried different ways but in output, it is displaying $(date) as a string. To test it easily, use the following command to display it on the terminal itself.

```
sudo mpstat 1 1 | grep Average | sed -E 's|Average:|$(date)|g'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell does not substitute anything in a string enclosed in single quotes. Use double quotes instead.

You don't need the `-E` option, and you can do without `grep` and without `sudo`:

```
mpstat 1 1 | sed -n "s|Average:|$(date)|gp"
```

`-E` is not needed because you don't use extended regular expressions here. `-n` prevents `sed` from printing by default, and the `p` at the end prints the line only when "Average:" is in fact replaced.

The [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) is not bad for learning, by the way.

Comment: Thank you so much  for mentioning the grep and -E also.